# Coroutine error when running an async function

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have simple function that replies with a certain message when a person uses `@here` or `@everyone` in the server

```
    #Ping related stuff
    if message.mention_everyone:
        if checker_ping(message.author.id):
            await message.channel.send("U used a ping")
```

and the function `checker_ping`

```
async def checker_ping(id):
    for i in data:
        if id == i:
            return True
```

where `data` is nothing but a list of userids

```
file = open('pings.txt', 'r+')
data = list(re.sub(":.", '', ''.join(file.readlines())).splitlines())
```

what it does is if a person with the userid specified in the `ping.txt` uses the `@here` or `@everyone` it sends a message as specified in the code

The problem arises when someone uses it

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'checker_ping' was never awaited
  if checker_ping(message.author.id):
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

i tried searching it up and doing various things such as storing the return value in a variable and then running it, awaiting the if statement and much more and all of them resulted in the same error

but the bot still replies
[image: Python discord bot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you tried to defined a synchronous function as an asynchronous one.

Code:

```
with open("stacktest/pings.txt","r+") as f:
    data = list(re.sub(":.", '', ''.join(f.readlines())).splitlines())
    print(data)

def checker_ping(userid):
    return userid in data

@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.mention_everyone:
        if checker_ping(str(message.author.id)):
            await message.channel.send("U used a ping")
```

Smaller mistakes:

- You tried comparing a number to a string. In your function `message.author.id` returns an integer and you compared that to a list element which is a string.
- This is not really a mistake but an optimization. I made the function return if userid is in the data with `return userid in data`. This creates a boolean which will either return True or False.
- You opened a file with simply `file = open()` but never closed it. Use `with open() as something` instead as i provided. (This is mostly for optimization too)

Comment: Thanks, man. My root problem was that I was comparing a string with an int. I changed it to ```data = list(map(int, list(re.sub(":"), '', ''.join(file.readlines())).splitlines())))``` and as you mentioned, i was trying to make a synchronous program asynchronous, fixed the problem, cool!

Answer (score 2):

The error arises because the function that you have made `checker_ping` is an asynchronous function, and has to be awaited.

```
    if message.mention_everyone:
        if await checker_ping(message.author.id):
            await message.channel.send("U used a ping")
```

Also it would be much better if you would use the `in` keyword instead of looping through the data.

```
async def checker_ping(id):
    return id in data
```